# Serial Error Correction

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, communication

I currently have a setup where I take serial output from Arduino 1 and push it through a transmitter to the receiver of Arduino 2 where it is fed back into the serial input and further processed. I want to ensure that there is as little error as possible and recover the data wherever possible.

I have come across the syndrome decoding technique which seems to be the ideal one for me, but I am confused as to how I would go about implementing it.

I know that the Arduino Serial transfers data byte by byte, each being 8 bits, but do not know how this data is sent over the serial connection (i.e. how the start & stop bits & parity is implemented).

I would assume that a solution to this could either involve modifying the data in the buffer or reading it from the buffer and then operating upon it. I could also use adjacent bytes of data for error correction, but this seems wasteful.

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: Which "syndrome decoding technique" are you considering?  It will probably affect the approach.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wide world of Communications.  You are asking about ["Error Detection and Correction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction).  This is different from "framing", which allows you to determine when a message starts and ends.

With "error detection", you know there was an error, but you can't necessarily recover from it.  With "correction", you know there was an error and you *can* determine what was originally sent.

This *always* requires extra bytes.  There are many schemes, but the [Fletcher checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum) for Error Detection is easy to implement, fast, and only requires 2 extra bytes in the message (4 if hex digits).

The generic approach is to use a [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  In complicated message protocols, there would be nested state machines: the inner-most would probably determine framing, the next one out might looks at addressing, etc.  Any or all of those layers could use Error Detection and/or Correction.

For your simple "protocol", a single state machine is probably sufficient.  The states might be IDLE, RX_PAYLOAD and RX_CS.  As characters are received, they are processed according to the current state and occasionally change the state variable.

```
while (Serial.available()) {
  uint8_t c = Serial.read();
  switch (state) {
    case IDLE:
      if (c == MSG_START)
        state = RX_PAYLOAD;
      break;
    case RX_PAYLOAD:
      if (c == MSG_END) {
        state = RX_CS;
        cs = 0;
        csCount = 0;
      } else if (length < MAX_LENGTH-1) {
        msg[ length++ ] = c;
      }
      break;
    case RX_CS:
      //  Add in the next hex CS digit
      cs = cs * 16 + fromHex(c);
      if (++csCount == 2) {
        // both digits received, see if the CS matches
        if (cs == csOfMsg( msg, length )) {
          // Handle the message
          msg[ length ] = '\0';
          Serial.println( msg );
        } else {
          Serial.println( F("Bad message!") );
        }
        state = IDLE;
      }
      break;
  } // end switch
} // end while
```

There are entire books written on protocols and their design.  This is just a made-up example to give you an idea of how it should be structured: a finite state machine, driven by received character "events".

Sometimes you can compute the checksum as the characters are received, like Fletcher.  Here, it waits until the entire message plus 2 CS bytes are received.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used a buffer and a delimiter. Specificaly: The reading is placed on the byte array untill the delimiter is reached.

### For example

From the arduino IDE serial monitor im sending this: `CAT;`

Each letter will be placed inside the byte array and this will stop when the `;` sign is entered. This migh be usefull because you can send the bytes whenever you can and they will remain in the array.

```
void loop(){
if(Serial.available() > 0) {
 
 char rec = Serial.read();

 if(rec == '.'){
    Serial.print("Here: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(attitude); i++){
       Serial.print(attitude[i]); //print
       attitude[i] = (char)0;
    }
    attitudePointer = 0;
    Serial.println();
    
 }else{
   if(attitudePointer <= sizeof(attitude)){
      attitude[attitudePointer] = rec;
      attitudePointer++;
    }
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't match your description!  That code waits for a period (full stop), not a semicolon.  And it's a little misleading to use `attitudePointer`, when it is actually an index, not a pointer.